# what is the best way for exceptional handling in MVC (Base_Controller vs CustomHandleErrorAttribute)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, exception

I am doing exceptional handling in MVC in Three models.

```
 public class CustomHandleErrorAttribute : HandleErrorAttribute
{  
    public override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {
       //logging           

    }
}
```

and

```
 public class Base_Application : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        //Logging
    }
}
```

and

```
   public class Base_Controller : Controller
{
    protected override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {
        //Logging;

    }

}
```

If i throw a sample exception from Code it is catching by `CustomHandleErrorAttribute` and `Base_Controller` .

and

In `Base_Application` I am logging exceptions same is logging by Elmah.

So I want to know the best way in all cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a base controller, I would suggest go with this approach

```
public class CustomHandleErrorAttribute : HandleErrorAttribute
{  
    public override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {
       //logging           

    }
}
```

And decorate base controller, with custom attribute

```
[CustomHandleError]
public class Base_Controller : Controller
{

}
```

So also you can reuse the attribute, if you add a controller which don't need a base controller in the future.

Also go through this wonderful [**article**](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2010/06/28/action-filter-versus-controller-base-class.aspx) to decide whether to use a base controller or an ActionFilter.

`Application_Error` event can be used to catch errors which are not caught by a page-level error handler.

Comment: Any reason why base control? and what abt Elmah vs Application_Error

Comment: Go through the article to understand why base controller and check my edit about Application_Error event.